# Shopify - Private App, 401 unauthorized (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, api, oauth, shopify, api-key

Since yesterday I try to juste get a list of my products via Shopify Javascript API.

**1. Shopify Javascript API**

I tried to follow this tutorial: https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/

My code:

```
const shopClient = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
  apiKey: 'e1616e793836bd1178d34dfa124667cf',
  appId: '6',
  domain: 'cordillot-store.myshopify.com'
})

// fetch a product using resource id
shopClient.fetchAllProducts()
  .then(function (product) {
    console.log(product)
  })
  .catch(function () {
    console.log('Request failed')
  })
```

And I got a 403: [image: 403]

**2. Private App instructions**

So, I decided to follow the instruction after creating my private app [image]

My code:

```
import request from 'superagent'

request
  .get('https://e1616e793836bd1178d34dfa124667cf:c796f294364021868d7123239606146f@cordillot-store.myshopify.com/admin/products.json')
  .end((error, response) => {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(response)
  })
```

And I got a 401: [image]

But, this URL works well with cURL

```
curl -X GET https://e1616e793836bd1178d34dfa124667cf:c796f294364021868d7123239606146f@cordillot-store.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
```

**3. Public App**
After I created a Public Application and try to connect with Oauth (https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/authentication/oauth).

Everything runs good until I tried to reach the URL 'http://[SHOP_NAME]/admin/oauth/access_token', I got an 404.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You posted private credentials in your question. Please invalidate this information in your store admin to ensure that your app is not compromised or other sensitive data is confiscated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i tried shopify javascript sdk https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/ . getting same error because of Permission in admin app. Follow the below steps fix that issue.

1) Login into shop admin page
2) Add Sales Channels as Buy Button.
3)Choose Buy Button in side menu and create new JavaScript Buy SDK token then try [create token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XP89.png)

4) Then try your code
Example Code

```
const shopClient = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
  accessToken: '1c51f10dc2a3bd1e7dc31974cdc06aef',
  appId: '6',
  domain: 'shopify-deals-dev.myshopify.com'
});

shopClient.fetchAllProducts()
  .then(function (product) {
    console.log(product);
  })
  .catch(function () {
    console.log('Request failed');
  });
```